# how to change for loop to a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, split

I'm having trouble converting my code to a while loop? I completed my code as a for loop, but it has to be the while loop. I'm not too sure how to start?

This is what the questions asks for:

> Write a function split() to split a list every 4th element using a while loop from the given list.
> Given list: s = “ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan”

Here's my code:

```
def split(s):
    s = 'ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan' 
    split_string = []
    n = 4 

    for index in range(0, len(s), n):
        split_string.append(s[index : index + n])

    print(split_string)
```

Comment: Why does it have to be a `while` loop? `for` loops are better.

Comment: i agree! it's just the requirement for it @ggorlen

Comment: I’m guessing it’s for an assignment. There aren’t much simpler ways to split a string.

Comment: Remember, a for loop is just syntactic sugar applied to a while loop.

Comment: @ggorlen for loops aren't always better, in some cases a while loop is suffice.

Comment: @ggorlen You're viewing it the wrong way. They're not learning how to split strings, they're learning how to write `while` loops. Almost all exercises at this level are contrived.

Comment: @jbflow Almost never in a language as high-level as Python, in my experience. `while` loops are un-Pythonic and definitely worse for this task, and for just about any other I can think of except infinite loops.

Comment: That's why it's hard to find a simple exercise that teaches how to write `while` loops. The times when they're actually useful are more complex in Python, but that will likely require more advanced skills.

Comment: `s = "ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan"` is not a list.

Comment: @ggorlen Often Python is being used as the language in a general CS 101 class. So they're teaching programming concepts, and `while` is common to many languages.

Comment: BTW, `while True:` is very common.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is just a specific case of `while` when it comes to loops. Take the basic `for` loop:

```
for index in range(10):
   print(index)
```

written as a `while` loop:

```
index = 0 
while index < 10:
   print(index)
   index += 1
```

if you want to add skip functionality to select every nth item we can do so like this:

```
n = 4
index = 0 
while index < 10:
   print(index)
   index += n
```

This way we start at x=0 and increment it by n each time.

Answer (score 0):

The easies way to do it is like this:

```
def split(s):


      split_string = []
      n = 4
      index = 0
      while(len(s) != 0):
            split_string.append(s[:n])
            s = s[n:]

      print(split_string)
s = "ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan"
split(s)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Answer (score 0):

This was already thoroughly answered by the community, so I decided to go off the rails a bit. Whether its a school exercise or not, I wanted to throw some extra sauce to show another way you can go about it!

Here's the mild while loop you ordered:

```py
def split(s, n, index=0, split_string=[]):
      while(len(s) != 0):
            split_string.append(s[:n])
            s = s[n:]

      print(split_string)
split(s="ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan", n=4)
```

Well, thats **booring**... how about we explore a bit!

**Getting Spicy:**

I liked @Loai's answer, but added some *recursive* flare ->

```py
def spicy_split(s, n, split_string=[]):
    if len(s) != 0:
        split_string.append(s[:n])
        s = s[n:]
        return spicy_split(s, n, split_string)
    else:
        print(split_string)
s = "ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan"
spicy_split(s=s,n=4)
```

yeet! Still get the same response answer. ****Billy Mays voice***  "BUT WAIT THERE'S MORE!"

**Oh Lawd Thats HOT:**

Let me introduce you to the wonderful world of generators! Unlike me in grade 10, these are pretty cool. Why? Well, because they can iterate over a HUGE data set, but only load the given portion its operating on into RAM, and allows you to run computations on things your computer would otherwise fail on. Lets have a look ->

```py
# generator
def oh_lawd_thats_HOT(s, n):
    while len(s) > 0:
        split = s[:n]
        s = s[n:]
        yield split
        
s = "ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan"

# the oh_lawd_thats_HOT function is actually an iterable! Have a look:
print([s for s in oh_lawd_thats_HOT(s=s,n=4)])
```

Most are probably "done with this idiot", and have probably downvoted me to oblivion before moving on. But there's no quit in this idiot!

**OFF THE TOP ROPES:**

Me: "Hey, you want some free async?"
Everyone Else: "no thanks, I don't do drugs."

We're officially *getting funky* now.

Well, I present you the asynchronous generator! Just like the regular generator, but 2x as fast, 3x as likely to confuse your colleagues when they review your code, and 4x as likely to break in a production application. Make sure your standing! ->

```py
import asyncio
# async generator
async def OFF_THE_TOP_ROPES(s, n, split_string=[]):
    for index in range(0, len(s), n):
        yield split_string.append(s[index : index + n])
    
        
s = "ellepeepizzikeeksaasannanoonnaan"
async for s in OFF_THE_TOP_ROPES(s=s,n=4):
    print(s)
```